# get array returned from function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, observer-pattern

This is my function i want value of value array outside this function in this same class , i am calling this function in a setter method where id sets like setId(id:string){ this.onChange(id)}

```
class ModalShowComponent implements OnInit {
  onChange(id) {
    this.xyzService.getCodes(id).subscribe(
      list => {
        var value = [];
        list.forEach((object) => {
          value.push(object.payload.val());
        });
        // some code
        return value;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
class ModalShowComponent implements OnInit {
  public value:[]=[];

  onChange(id) {
    this.xyzService.getCodes(id).subscribe(
      list => {
        list.map((object) => {
          this.value.push(object.payload.val());
        });
      });
  }
}
```